# JavaScript math, round to two decimal places in Jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I have some code

```
{{if commission}}              
    <td>${profit - commission}</td>   
{{else}}
    <td>${profit}</td>
{{/if}}
```

profit = `5`;

commission = `2.145`

result = `2.855999999999`

I need `2.856`

Please help me

I try to use `(${profit - commission}).toFixed(2)` - but it does not work.

Comment: Use a bignum library, floats for cash are trash.

Comment: May be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Comment: How about `${(profit - commission).toFixed(2)}`

Answer (score 13):

Use simply `toFixed(3)` .it will select the 3 digits value after the  dot value

```
var s=2.855999999999;
alert(s.toFixed(3))
```

`OP`: 2.856

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9f88h/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = 2.855999999999;
result =   result.toFixed(2); //returns string fixed to 2 decimal places
result =   parseFloat(result);//returns double 2 decimal places
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mentioned as using in jQuery template

parseFloat should be inside ${}

> ${ parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)}

```
{{if commission}}              
    <td>${parseFloat(profit - commission).toFixed(2)}</td>   
{{else}}
    <td>${profit}</td>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var result = 2.855999999999;
result = Math.round(result * 1000) / 1000;
console.log(result ); //  ----> 2.856
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/azT97/)**

Comment: Why `Math.ceil()`? `2.85511111111` will still yield `2.856`.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Phj9m/273/)

You can use `Math.round()`

```
var num = 2.855999999999
num = Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000
alert(num);
```

Use 100 for .xx etc :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parseFloat(${profit - commission}).toFixed(3);
```